# Composition of functions where the domain equals the range

Tags: real-analysis

Problem:

(1) If $h:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and its image on this domain is $[0,1]$ implies there exits an $x*$ in $[0,1]$ s.t $h(x^{*})=x^{*}$

(2)Let $a>0$. $f(y)=ay$ is continuous on the reals.

(3)Let $m:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:G \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where X is $m(d)$ is contained in $G$. Since $m$ cts at d and $g$ cts at $m(d)$ then $g \circ m(x)$ is cts at d in D.

Using only (1),(2),(3) show If $j:[0,t] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[0,t]$ and its image on this domain is $[0,t]$ implies there exits an $x^{**}$ in $[0,1]$ s.t $j(x^{**})=x^{**}$

My thoughts:

*I intend g,f,x are not related to the previous mentions of them*

Define $j=g \circ b \circ f(x)$

Define $f$ by $x/t$, $b$ by $x$ and g by $tx$, where $f:[0,t] \rightarrow [0,1]$, $b:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$and $g:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,t]$

Then there is an $x^{..}$ in $[0,1]$ s.t b($x^{..}$)=$x^{..}$

and since $x^{..}$ is from the range of g there is an $x^{**}$ that maps to it from $[0,t]$

and $b(x)$ is in the domain of $f$, then there is something that maps from $x^{..}=x^{**}$ to something in $[0,t]$.....

My question:

However, I am not sure where I go from here/whether what I have done is right?

Answer (score 0):

If we define $h : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ by
$$
h(x) = \frac{j(tx)}{t},
$$
then by (1) there is a point $x^{*}$ in $[0, 1]$ such that $h(x^{*}) = x^{*}.$ Since $j(x) = th\big(\frac{x}{t}\big),$
$$
j(tx^{*}) = th(x^{*}) = tx^{*}.
$$
Hence, if we set $x^{**} = tx,$ then $j(x^{**}) = x^{**}.$

Comment: I had made a typo in my original post, sorry, I have corrected it now.

Comment: What was the typo?

Comment: previously had by mistake stated $[0,1]$ s.t $h(x^{**})=x^{**}$

Comment: I didn't notice, but I don't think that affects my answer. Essentially the point is that (2) guarantees that $x/t$ and and $tx$ are continuous, which means $h$ is continuous, by (3). The condition that $j$ maps $[0,t]$ onto $[0, t]$ then implies that $h$ maps $[0,1]$ onto $[0,1]$ since $tx$ maps $[0,1]$ one-to-one to $[0,t]$ and $x/t$ maps $[0,t]$ one-to-one to $[0,1]$. Hence $h$ satisfies the hypotheses of (1), and the argument proceeds as above.